# CSS3 Flexible Box Model - Boxes Should change location based on space available

Tags: html, css, firefox

Please take a look at the following JSFiddle and drag to resize the "Result" window for exactly what I am trying to achieve on (at least) Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer 11:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tKZf/

Please note that you must be using Firefox when viewing the JSFiddle, or you will not see the behaviour that I desire. Rather, you'll see the behaviour that I want to avoid.

Basically I want to have some boxes on a page. When there is enough room, I want the page to show all of the boxes side by side, and when there is not enough room, I want the boxes to start relocating **exactly** like they do in Firefox. I had been trying to reinvent the wheel on exactly this issue about a year ago and it was a pain and wouldn't always work. Now that I've found the CSS3 Flexible Box Model it seems this has already been done for me, but it's only working in Firefox for me.

I **do not** want to use ul/li for this effect, if at all possible.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="number">1</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="number">2</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="number">3</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="number">4</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="number">5</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box
{
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: black;
margin: 40px;
color: #555;
font-family: arial;
padding: 0px;

display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;
}

.number
{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
```

I've tried adding the following, but it hasn't seemed to affect Internet Explorer 11 or Chrome at all:

```
/* Internet Explorer 10 */
display:-ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-pack:center;
-ms-flex-align:center;

/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
display:box;
box-pack:center;
box-align:center;
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the old version of flexbox.  Use newer specification: http://jsfiddle.net/D398s/.  Should work in Chrome and Firefox.

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="number">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="number">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="number">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="number">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="number">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container > div {
    margin: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 40px;
    flex: 0 0 40px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > div > div {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me in the newest versions of Firefox and Chrome, as well as IE11. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a container with `display: flex` set, and you need the `-webkit-` versions of the style properties.

[That works in Chrome for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/85dQj/)

Comment: I have Version 36.0.1985.125 m of Google Chrome installed and the boxes are all showing up in a vertical line for me when I go to your JSFiddle. Are they showing up horizontally like in Firefox for you? Which version of Chrome do you have if so?

Comment: I'm running 35 and it's telling me to update it :) I'll do that and see what happens, and post the results here.

Comment: @AlexPodworny with version `36.0.1985.125` it also works fine for me - that fiddle shows the boxes arrayed horizontally, just like Firefox.

Comment: https://www.anonimg.com/img/eeaef33862d6485d13f05e9eb938d71d.png
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AlexPodworny do you have `body { display: flex; }` set?

Comment: I just tried it with that value in Firefox, that's making the boxes get larger and smaller when I resize the window, instead of moving the boxes around.